Confusion about filtration in context of stochastic integration
I am extremely confused by the assumptions on the filtration when defining the Ito integral.
In the book "Basic Stochastic Processes" by Brzezniak et al., it is said on page 180: "Throughout this chapter W(t) will denote a Wiener process adapted to a filtration F_t (...)."
Further on, on page 191, it is claimed as part of Properties of stochastic integral, that the stochastic integral has the martingale property. However, as far as I understand, this is NOT true in general, since for the martingale property to be true, we need additional assumption on the filtration (namely, that the filtration is independent of future increments of the Brownian motion W(t)). Even more mind-boggling is that they seemingly give a proof of this result (which, if I am correct, must be wrong), without this additional assumption...
In general, there is a lot of confusion about what exactly is assumed. Can someone very clearly and unambiguously state what is assumed about the filtration? Also, how does the Ito integral depend on the filtration?

You are not correct. Stochastic integrals w.r.t. Brownian motion are local martingales. When the integrand is in $L^2$ they are true martingales. It is hard to believe that the entire stochastic calculus literature made that same error that you think you have found.
